# What is the best way to update/save a list of entities?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a list of new/detached entities, some of which might be already present in the DB, but I don't know apriori which ones. I want to save the entities in this list so that

- existing entities are updated (the identity of the entity is based on a natural id, **which is not the primary key**)
- new entities are persisted

What's the most natural/idiomatic/efficient way to do that using:

- Spring Data JPA
- plain JPA/Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following for the scenario where there are two lists: one with the new entities and one with the stored entities but the stored entities do not have the @Id field populated.

Create a repo method that loads each of the existing entities from the DB, eg `Optional<EntityType> findByFooAndBar(String foo, String bar)`. Update the fields in **these loaded** entities from those lacking the @Id in the existing entities list. Add these read & updated entities to the list of new entities.

Then Spring Data JPA and plain JPA use `respository.saveAll(collectionOfEntities)`. It updates existing entities and creates new ones.

If you have control of the DB then scrap the current PK and replace it with a candidate key comprised of the natural key elements. Presumably they are unique. Then a simple saveAll of new and existing can be left to JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: I have added one important detail which sadly makes this obvious solution not possible (AFAIK). The natural id of the entities is not DB primary key so I would have to probably fetch the entities from DB first and then somehow do a merge. That's the part of the problem I don't know how to do efficiently.

Comment: Obviously, if the primary key field/s of the entity cannot be populated without reading the matching DB records then the records will have to be read to populate these fields.

Comment: Yeah, my question is then how exactly to "merge" my new data to the existing fetched ones. Suppose I already have two lists: one with the new entities and one with the stored entities (possibly of smaller size). How do I combine these two so that DB state is equivalent to the first list while reusing existing stored entities?

Comment: I have updated my answer to focus on the existing entities lacking primary key data. I don't think there is any magical way around.

Comment: The devil is in the details. I'm basically asking how the "Update the fields in these loaded entities" part can be done efficiently. I was hoping for something like `existingEntity.merge(newEntity)`in stead of copying the state field by field manually.